# No sound using mpg123 visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to play a song using mpg123 in a visual c++ project, I'm using a code from here but I can't find how to make sound. The code doesn't have errors, it works right but close immediately, This is the code, Thanks:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mpg123.h>

#define INBUFF  16384
#define OUTBUFF 32768

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    mpg123_handle *mh;
    const char* filename;
    filename="D:/Jose.mp3";
    unsigned char *buffer;

    size_t buffer_size;

    size_t done;
    int err;

    int channels, encoding;
    long rate;

    mpg123_init();
    mh = mpg123_new(NULL, &err);
    buffer_size = mpg123_outblock(mh);
    buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(unsigned char));

    /* open the file and get the decoding format */
    mpg123_open(mh, filename);
    mpg123_getformat(mh, &rate, &channels, &encoding);

    /* set the output format and open the output device */
    int m_bits = mpg123_encsize(encoding);
    int m_rate = rate;
    int m_channels = channels;


    /* decode and play */

    for (int totalBtyes = 0 ; mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK;) {
        totalBtyes += done;     
    }

    /* clean up */
    free(buffer);
    mpg123_close(mh);
    mpg123_delete(mh);
    mpg123_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're coding C++, why are you using e.g. `malloc`/`free` instead of `new`/`delete`?

Comment: And your program only *reads* the file you provide, it doesn't attempt to *play* anything.

Comment: Sorry I'm new using mpg123, I thought that the part of decode and play was for play the song, Do you know how to play a song using mpg123?